# Operating Arithmetic Operations in SQL SELECT

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck on this problem :
Hello everybody (don't know why it does not appear on the first line...)

I have 2 tables :

```
-factures (invoices)
-commandes_clients (orders)
```

Each table contain unique `id_client`.

I'm trying to get and sort the average amount order of each client based on invoices amount : (total amount invoice for each client / number of orders of the same client)

```
Client 1 Average order amount 1254.21
Client 2 Average order amount 951.88
Client 3 Average order amount 891.11
...
```

I would like to sort by the average amount to get the client palmares

```
Table facture contains :
id_client, invoice_number, total amount
Table commandes_clients contains :
id_client
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id_client,sum(total_amount)/count(invoice_number) as avg 
FROM factures group by id_client order by avg;
```

Or:

```
 SELECT id_client,sum(total_amount)/count(CC.id) as avg 
    FROM factures FA
    INNER JOIN commandes_clients CC ON FA.id_client=CC.id_client
    group by FA.id_client order by avg;
```

Try above query.

Comment: Hi, thanks, sum(invoice_number) is not a total of invoice for the client but an incremented number. The operation should be like : sum(total_amount)/count(commandes_clients). We need to get how many orders each client done

Comment: @jpsFR made changes for same..!! Will it resolve your issue??

Comment: I don't know how to do because total_amount is from factures and to get how many orders each client done is another table (commandes_ clients). The operation should be client total invoice / client total orders... And then sort by best average

Comment: @jpsFR You only mention `Table commandes_clients contains :
id_client
`

Comment: `id_client ` only one column is there

Comment: Yes, commandes_clients contains id_client. The idea is to get the number of orders the client made with this table. The id_client can be join to the other table factures wich contain the amount of invoices. id_client is the joint

Comment: Table commandes_clients : id  / numero_cde  / date_commande  / id_client

Comment: only id_client?

Comment: Table commandes_clients : id / numero_cde / date_commande  / id_client